# illegal character error on all javascripts when hosted to vps

Tags: javascript, hosting, vps

i uploaded my website on a vps server at hostinger
it was working fine on localhost and other shared server but showing error on vps hosting

SyntaxError: illegal character

tried changing the url
checked all the urls

if this error is resolved my website would word smoothly like a charm

Comment: Do you see any illegal character? (I mean, pls look at the response you get. With the devtools or just opening the url of the js file in the browser.)

Comment: thanks roland for the reply, my domain actually corrupted the js files during ftp upload